# Is there a pretty way to yield if in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

Is there a way to make this code prettier?

```
strong = li.find_all("strong")
if strong:
  yield li.find_all("strong")
```

I mean something like this:

```
strong = li.find_all("strong")
yield li.find_all("strong") if strong
```

Comment: How is hiding the condition better?

Comment: Whether these two are equivalent depends on what `li.find_all` does/returns, but wouldn't that normally be written `strong = li.find_all("strong")` and `if strong: yield strong`?  The only "unpretty" part to my eyes is the duplication (which could be necessary, I guess.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use:

```
strong = li.find_all("strong")
if strong:
    yield strong
```

instead of calling `find_all()` *again* (which, in BeautifulSoup, gives the same result but does the work *again*).

There is no 'conditional yield'. You could play tricks with `yield from` but I'd recommend against that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```py
strong = li.find_all("strong")
strong and (yield strong)
```

Its concise and pretty but it can be hard to understand what it does during debugging.